# Criar PDF com 2 paginas

Tags: lua, pdf

Estou utilizando este exemplo: [forums.mediabox.fr/wiki/tutoriaux/pao/construction_fichier_pdf](http://forums.mediabox.fr/wiki/tutoriaux/pao/construction_fichier_pdf) para criar um cabeçalho para o pdf. O problema é que no meu exemplo só consigo criar uma pagina, mas quero 2 paginas. Utilizo este código em ficheiro a parte e inclui o exemplo:

```
footer = "/PDF/f_pdf.lua"
header = "/PDF/h_pdf.lua"
fichier = "example.pdf"
h = io.open( header, "rb" )
r = io.open( fichier, "wb+" )
```

e depois escrevo no ficheiro exemplo.pdf. Como posso então criar as 2 paginas?

Comment: Boa tarde @akm, eu não entendi, você quer colocar códigos .lua dentro de um .pdf? Por que o `/pdf/f_pdf.lua` parece um script lua apenas e não um outro pdf.